# Selenium to navigate American Fact Finder drop downs

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, drop-down-menu, selenium-chromedriver, census

I am new to Python 3.X and need to write a script to automate the process downloading US Census data from American Fact Finder. I am using selenium webdriver and the code I have so far is:

```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromePath)

    #make driver navigate to American Fact Finder Download Center
    driver.get('https://factfinder.census.gov/faces/nav/jsf/pages/download_center.xhtml')

    #Make driver click 'Next' to go to Dataset page
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="nextButton"]''').click()

    #this is where I need to locate the drop down and select American Community Survey'
```

On the 'Dataset' page I need to select 'American Community Survey' from the drop down list, but no matter how I try to locate the drop down(xpath, id, value, etc.) running the script returns `NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:`

I need help with locating the correct element and selecting 'American Community Survey' from the drop down menu.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to solve it myself.

For anyone wondering, the error was caused because selenium was trying to find the element before the page had finished loading. The working code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chromePath = r'chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromePath)

#make driver navigate to American Fact Finder Download Center

driver.get('https://factfinder.census.gov/faces/nav/jsf/pages/download_center.xhtml')
#Make driver click 'Next' to go to Dataset
driver.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="nextButton"]''').click() #needs to be triple quoted
#make driver wait while page loads
timeout = 5
try:
    element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="filterDimensionListId'))
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
except TimeoutException:
    print ("Timed out waiting for page to load") 
#Choose ACS 5-year from drop down
driver.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="filterDimensionListId"]/option[2]''').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code to get.

```
  select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('filterDimensionListId'))      
    for index in range(len(select.options)):
        select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('filterDimensionListId'))
        select.select_by_index(1)
```

// you can use other selection method.